# What is the difference between SIGABRT and SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, coredump

I made the core dumped error with the two pieces of codes below:

```
//test.cpp
int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 100;
    delete p;
    delete p;
    return 0;
}

//test2.cpp
int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    *p = 100;
    delete p;
    *p = 111;
    std::cout<<*p<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Gdb told me that the first piece of code got core dumped because of the signal SIGABRT, whereas the second piece of code got core dumped because of the signal SIGSEGV.

Could you tell what is the difference?

Comment: Here's a nice listing of what the various signals mean: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/SIG_types

Comment: Nothing in that question is C. Please take more care with selecting the tags in future questions.

Comment: Both snippets have undefined behavior and may cause any of those signals, or none at all. So they don't demonstrate anything

Comment: @VTT With some discussion on why each is UB, that would be a nice answer.

Comment: Explanation on why each is UB can be find among older questions, and it has nothing to do with the title of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SIGABRT is **explicitly detected and signaled** by the implementation of *delete* whose detected the invalidity of the second delete. It is launch by calling the *abort* function

The SIGSEGV is different, it is **undergoing** rather than detected by a check in a library like the previous, it is launch through the memory management of the OS

see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/SIG_types

Comment: I see you've copied link from the first comment, but the rest of the answer is just an attempt to explain UB

Comment: @VTT all the difference in the detection mode

Comment: @VTT rather than just criticizing please put your answer  to allow all of us to learn what is a real answer ;-)

Comment: @bruno Constructive criticism is something that is good. I believe VTT is trying to help you with your answer, not hurt it ...

Comment: @FantasticMrFox yes, sure, I was ironic. But yourself take care to not hurt him by writing his name badly, he is **V**TT not **C**TT (this is a joke, don't get that bad both of you ^^ ). <edit> Oh, you corrected

Answer (score 3):

Both of these examples are *undefined behaviour*, this means according to c++ the compiler (and system) can do whatever it wants.

- In case 1, there is likely a check for the double delete of a pointer, therefore `SIGABRT` is signaled. `SIGABRT` means *abnormal termination condition, as is e.g. initiated by abort()*.
- In case 2, the system detects your deference of a deleted pointer and
  creates a `SIGSEGV` signal. `SIGSEGV` means *invalid memory access (segmentation fault)*

But both are still UB, so this is just a feature of your current compiler/os/system. The difference between the errors is clear from the definition of the errors [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/SIG_types). One is an abort, usually generated by the compiler or coder. One is caused by invalid memory access, usually signaled by the operating system or hardware.

Comment: this does not explain difference between SIGABRT and SIGSEGV either

Comment: @VTT Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting a pointer twice is undefined behavior, which means anything can happen. In this case, it results in the `SIGABRT` signal being issued.

Accessing memory which does not belong to the program is also undefined behavior which in this case results in segmentation fault and `SIGSEGV` is issued.

- `SIGABRT` indicates an error detected by the program itself and reported by calling [`abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort).
- `SIGSEGV` indicates an invalid access to valid memory.